# Deploying application removes account from account manager

Tags: android, accountmanager

Every time I deploy my application on device, it removes all accounts from AccountManager associated with that application. Is there any way to prevent this ?

Comment: What do you mean by deploy? I am doing a "adb install -r a.apk" and the account I created stays put.

Comment: It was my own fault. I was doing 
     **adb -s "d" shell pm uninstall -k net.pk.app**
So that removed account data. I thought it does uninstall on it's own, but apparently that is not the case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my deployment script I had

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k my.app.pck
```

So that removed all accounts

Answer (score 1):

I am doing a "adb install -r a.apk" and the account I created stays put. Sure you are not removing the app's data with a flag?